# Angular calling a custom service - can't find source of call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a module `app.posts`. Several routes within this module work fine, but here I'm trying to display a `create post` form:

```
.state('app.posts', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/news',
    template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-right-big smooth"></div>'
})
.state('app.posts.show', {
    url: '/{id}',
    templateUrl: 'app/posts/show.html',
    resolve: {
            deps: ['uiLoad',
                function( uiLoad ){
                    return uiLoad.load( [
                        'app/posts/show.controller.js'
                        ]);
            }]
    }
})
.state('app.posts.create', {
    url: '/create',
    templateUrl: 'app/posts/create.html',
    resolve: {
            deps: ['uiLoad',
                function( uiLoad ){
                    return uiLoad.load( [
                        'app/posts/create.controller.js'
                        ]);
            }]
    }
})
```

The problem is that when I visit this page, it makes an api call from a custom service:

`GET /api/v1/node/create`

If I delete `create.controller.js` and `app/posts/create.html` I still get the same behaviour. It navigates to the correct page `/news/create`, and somehow makes this api call.

Doing some debugging on the service, it is clear that the method being called is `getPost()`. The service is defined as:

```
angular
    .module('app.posts')
    .service('Posts', Posts);

    Posts.$inject = ['$http'];

    function Posts($http) {

        var service = {
                getPosts:           getPosts,
                getPost:                getPost,
                addPost:            addPost,
                createPost:         createPost,
                deletePost:         deletePost
        };

        return service;

        /* ********************************
        *  Method: getPost
        ******************************** */
        function getPost(id) {
            var request = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '../api/v1/node/' + id,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type':     'application/json',
                    'Accept':               'application/json'
                }
            };

            return $http(request)
                .success(function(success){
                    return success;
                    console.log(success);
                })
                .error(function(error){

                    return error;
                });

        }
    }
```

I cannot figure out how this service is being called.

Comment: Try adding a console.trace() at the start of getPost and running the app in Google Chrome with the console open, might give some useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the order, you can add a regex

```
url: "/{id:[0-9]{1,8}}
```

For more information: [URL Parameters - Regex Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved. It was to do with the order in the state configuration.

`/create` was being interpreted as `/{id}` and was calling the `show` route. To solve this, I've re-ordered to put `app.post.create` second (below `app.post`).